# Getting error while upgrading my reactjs project with node version 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, sass, gyp

I am unable to update my ReactJS project from v16 to v18 and also facing this `gyp` error when I try to upgrade, I tried `sass` instead of `node-sass`.

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/projectPath/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.1.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node@18/18.16.0/bin/node" "/projectPath/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /projectPath/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v18.16.0
```